# website login without JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am trying to add a login button to my website without the `js/php sdk`, and following the help page for this on the FB dev site it tells me to add

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? client_id={xxxxxxxxxx} &redirect_uri={http://www.mydomain.com}
```

to my code but whenever I follow the link it gives me an error saying

The `redirect_uri` URL must be absolute

I'm pretty sure my url can not get anymore absolute then that, so I think it is an issue with something else but i have not been able to find anything to correct the problem

Comment: What url are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you replace the uri with the one to your site?

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1234567&redirect_uri=www.madderfish.com

Comment: can you post the actual code that you are using it would be helpful in seeing the problem.  Usually this happens when you leave the braces around the URL.

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? client_id=573647799336729 &redirect_uri=http://www.nowprovemewrong.com">Login</a>